# How to position buttons on a JFrame inside a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Ok, so I have:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
JButton button = new JButton("Add");
JPanel pane = new JPanel();

panel2.add(button);
frame.add(tabs);
myTab.addTab("Panel 2", pane);
```

I want to position the button in the bottom left hand corner.. How can this be made possible?

Comment: Try putting the button in a `JPanel` with `FlowLayout` aligned right and give the pane a `BorderLayout`, then `pane.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);`

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example). 2) Provide ASCII art (or an image with a simple drawing) of the *entire* GUI as it should appear in smallest size and (if resizable) with extra width/height.

Comment: Normally I do, but I didn't want my teachers plagiarism software to match up with my exact code.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a layout manager?
See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html for examples.